# Secure inserting value of $_POST['textarea'] into <textarea> HTML tag using PHP only

Tags: php, html, textarea

Is there any way to insert `$_POST['textarea']` into `<textarea>` without escaping shell special chars?
I do sth. like :

```
 <textarea>
     <?php 
           echo escapeshellcmd($_POST['textarea_field']) ; 
     ?>
 </textarea>
```

and I have a problem with `\` chars. I do not wont them in `<textarea>` but without `escapeshellcmd();` function it is possible to post HTML `</textarea>` tag and insert whatever from HTML to javascript code after.  Can you give me some advice regarding this problem, please? Can I insert posted data into `textarea` without `\` chars?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). `escapeshellcmd` is for a different purpose, namely escaping shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) yet?